# Is it correct to say z $\in x/\mathscr E$ when x/$\mathscr E$={y∈X| y$\mathscr E$x}?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Relation R is a subset of cartesian product, which has ordered pairs as its elements.

A relation R from A to B

⇔ R⊆ A×B

⇔ (a, b)$\in R$ ⇔ aRb

⇔ R={(a, b)| a, b ∈ A×B}

⇔ a is R- related to b

In symbols, R={(a, b)| (a, b) ∈ A×B}. So equivalence relation $\mathscr E$ has (a, b) as its elements.

Definitioin of equivalence class of x in X is in symbols,

x/$\mathscr E$={y∈X| y$\mathscr E$x} = {y$\in$X | (y, x)$\in\mathscr E$}

So when in the light of the above, in the proof of Theorem 3 (c), "$z\in x/\mathscr E$" is wrong because it should be in a form like $ (z, y)\in x/\mathscr E$. Isn't it? Or why x/$\mathscr E$ doesn't have ordered pairs as its elements?

"Theorem 3. Let $\mathscr E$ be an equivalence relation on a nonempty set X.
  Then

(a) Each x/$\mathscr E$ is a nonempty subset of X.

(b)  x/$\mathscr E \bigcap$ y/$\mathscr E \neq \emptyset$ if and only if x$\mathscr E$y.

(c) x$\mathscr E$y if and only if x/$\mathscr E$ = y/$\mathscr E$

[Proof]
 (a) Since $\mathscr E$ is reflexive, for each x$\in X$, we have $x \mathscr E$$x$. By Definition 6, $x \in x/\mathscr E$ and hence $x /\mathscr E$ is a nonempty subset of X.

(b) Since $\mathscr E$ is an equivalence relation and X$\neq \emptyset$, we have

x/$\mathscr E \bigcap$ y/$\mathscr E \neq \emptyset \Leftrightarrow \exists z (z \in x/ \mathscr E \land z \in y/\mathscr E )$

$\Leftrightarrow z\mathscr E$ $x \land z \mathscr E$ $y$ Def. 6

$\Leftrightarrow z\mathscr E$ x$\mathscr E$z $\land z \mathscr E$y $\mathscr E$ is symmetric.

$\Leftrightarrow z\mathscr E$ x$\mathscr E$z $\land z \mathscr E$y $\mathscr E$ is transitive.

(c) It follows immediately from (a) and (b) above that x/$\mathscr E$ = y/$\mathscr E$ We need to prove that

x$\mathscr E$y  $\Rightarrow x/\mathscr E = y/\mathscr E$

Let x$\mathscr E$y. Then

$z\in x/\mathscr E \Rightarrow z\mathscr E$x   Def. 6 x/$\mathscr E$={y∈X| y$\mathscr E$x} = {y∈X | (y, x)∈$\mathscr E$}

z$\mathscr E$x $\land x\mathscr E$y $\Rightarrow z\mathscr E$y $\space\space\space\mathscr E$ is transitive.

$\Rightarrow z\in y/\mathscr E$  Def. 6

Since z is arbitrary, it follows that x/$\mathscr E \subseteq y/\mathscr E$. A similar argument gives y/$\mathscr E \subseteq x/\mathscr E$; hence $x/\mathscr E \subset x/\mathscr E$
"

Source: Set Theory by You-Feng Lin, Shwu-Yeng T.Lin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no mistake.

$x/\mathscr{E}$ is the set of *first coordinates of* elements of $\mathscr{E}$ whose second coordinate is $x$.

A more concrete example: the binary relation "$<$" on $\mathbb{R}$ (usual interpretation) is a set of ordered pairs - e.g. $(0, 7)\in<$. Now for each real number $x$, the set $Big_x$ of reals bigger than $x$ is defined as $$\{y: (x, y)\in<\}.$$ But this is a set of reals, not a set of pairs of reals - e.g. $Big_0$ contains $7$, but not $(0, 7)$, since $(0, 7)$ is not a real which is bigger than $0$ (because in particular it's not a real at all).

Elements of an equivalence class are a *different type of thing* than elements of an equivalence relation - the latter are ordered pairs of the former. In particular, $x/\mathscr{E} \cap \mathscr{E}=\emptyset$ (generally).

Comment: first coordinates of $\mathscr E$! That clears up my misunderstanding.

Comment: So x/E is the set of first coordinate y of elements of E whose second coordinate is x

Answer (score 0):

No; the *equivalence class* $x/\mathcal E$ determined by the element $x$, with respect to an equivalence relation $\mathcal E$, is not a subset of $\mathcal E$, but the set formed by all those elements that are $\mathcal E$-related to $x$.